# list box asp.net selected problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

When I choose am item from "kategorije", new items are loaded into "SUB_kategorije", but when I choose the item from SUB_kategorije and when i click on button it shows me this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Line 101: kom.Parameters.Add("@podkategorija", SqlDbType.Text).Value =
          SUB_kategorije.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

This is my source...

[dod_pit.ascx](http://www.djkbf.hr/~atokic/dod_pit.ascx)

[dod_pit.ascx.cs](http://www.djkbf.hr/~atokic/dod_pit.ascx.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Page_Load`.  Change it to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource df = new SqlDataSource();
        df.ConnectionString = conn;
        df.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [Kategorije] FROM [kategorije] ";
        kategorije.DataSource = df;
        kategorije.DataTextField = "Kategorije";
        kategorije.DataValueField = "ID";
        kategorije.DataBind();
    }         
}
```

The problem is your rebinding `kategorije` every time your code does a postback so by the time `Button1_Click` runs, `kategorije` has been rebinding and reset so the `SelectedValue` is null.

When a postback happens your `Page_Load` code runs first, then the `Button1_Click` runs right after.  Moving that code into a `!IsPostBack` check will cause it to only run the first time your page loads and not again after so the `SelectedValue` will be available.

Comment: @Iodun You will need to provide more information as to what exactly is happening and what you expect to happen. Looking at your aspx code I don't understand why your SUB `ListBox` has `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` set.

Comment: I want to add posts(question) like i do that on yahoo answers.When i choose item in "kategorije" control,items can't be loaded in "SUB_kategorije" control..

Answer (score 0):

When I choose am item from "kategorije", new items are not loaded into "SUB_kategorije",Why?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource();
            ds.ConnectionString = conn;
            ds.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [Kategorije] FROM [kategorije] ";
            kategorije.DataSource = ds;
            kategorije.DataTextField = "Kategorije";
            kategorije.DataValueField = "ID";
            kategorije.DataBind();
            kategorije.SelectedIndex = 1;

            SqlDataSource dk = new SqlDataSource();
            dk.ConnectionString = conn;
            dk.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from pod_kategorije WHERE kat_id = " + kategorije.SelectedItem.Value;
            SUB_kategorije.DataSource = dk;
            SUB_kategorije.DataTextField = "pkategorija";
            SUB_kategorije.DataValueField = "ID";
            SUB_kategorije.DataBind();


        }







    }
    protected void kategorije_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            SqlDataSource dk = new SqlDataSource();
            dk.ConnectionString = conn;
            dk.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from pod_kategorije WHERE kat_id = " + kategorije.SelectedItem.Value;
            SUB_kategorije.DataSource = dk;
            SUB_kategorije.DataTextField = "pkategorija";
            SUB_kategorije.DataValueField = "ID";
            SUB_kategorije.DataBind();


    }
```